# reverse square root: in a Math lib or how to calculate it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, math

Does Actionscript have a function that would tell me what number the input is a square root of. For example:

```
4     //output 2, because 4 is the square root of 2
16    //output 4, because 16 is the square root of 4
```

Comment: umm, 4 is the square of 2.  2 is the square root of 4.

Comment: @dnagirl, hahaha, ok, I feel slightly stupid now **blushes**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't a "reverse" square root.  It's square root.

Use:

```
Math.sqrt (x);
```

[Here's the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Math.html#sqrt())

Answer (score 2):

you either want

`Math.sqrt(x)` (which returns the square root, i.e. `Math.sqrt(4) == 2`)

or

`x*x` (which returns the square, i.e. `4*4 = 16`) :)

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary469.html

Answer (score 1):

```
squareRoot=Math.sqrt(value);
```